# Running RSpec in debug mode

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is a short question: I am looking for a way to run specs in debug mode, with the `-u` switch, so that RSpec would drop to console **whenever** it failed, without having to add a `debugger` line into the code. Any pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Will answer my own question.

Following [this tutorial](http://wiki.github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/custom-formatters), I created a custom formatter, as in:

```
require "spec/runner/formatter/specdoc_formatter"

class DebuggerFormatter < Spec::Runner::Formatter::SpecdocFormatter
  def example_failed(example, counter, failure)
    super
    debugger if Kernel.respond_to?(:debugger)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

hakanensari, your code seems to break inside rspec. It'd be nice if we could break at the failing assert line.